# Trying to send sigquit output from Tomcat to a seperate file - file creates but is empty?

Tags: tomcat, kill, thread-dump

I'm trying to transfer the output of kill -3 PID to a different file using:

*kill -3 PID > /var/log/tomcat/ThreadDump*

However it only seems to be creating an empty file and I'm at a loss as to why?
When I perform a simple *kill -3 PID* it outputs correctly to catalina.out, however I can't work out how to proprely send the output to another location..

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the kill command is successful, the kill command doesn't print any output (at least, it doesn't on my Linux box).  So assuming the kill command is succeeding in your case, that would explain the zero length file.  Note: if the kill command fails (e.g. "no such process"), it will print error text on stderr, not stdout.  To capture both stdout and stderr, you'd need to do this: kill -3 PID > /var/log/tomcat/ThreadDump 2>&1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just implemented a rough hack to do this with `kill -3`. The rough outline of it is:

```
#! /bin/bash

TOMCAT_PID=`cat /opt/tomcat/work/tomcat.pid`
LOG_FILE=/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
NOWISH=`date +"%Y-%M-%d-%T"`
THREAD_DUMP_FILE=/var/mycompany/threaddumps/threaddump-$NOWISH.txt

# get current line count of catalina.out
CURRENT_LINES=`wc -l $LOG_FILE`

# perform the kill
kill -3 $TOMCAT_PID

# wait until we have 'Heap' mentioned in catalina.out _after_ the old line count
while [[ `tail -n+$CURRENT_LINES $LOG_FILE | grep 'Heap' | wc -l` == 0 && $ATTEMPTS != 10 ]]
do
        sleep 1
        ATTEMPTS=$((ATTEMPTS+1))
done

# tail catalina.out to get everything after the old line count into a separate file
tail -n+$CURRENT_LINES $LOG_FILE > $THREAD_DUMP_FILE
```

This is obviously a hack, but works well enough for us. Hope this helps someone.